# ASP.NET Disable Button After Validating Regular Expression of Textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I want to disable the asp button after the user submit the form with the correct regular expression

Here is my form

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="email" Font-Size="Large" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(')"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="S" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="myFunction2()" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Email" ValidationGroup="S" Visible="false" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

this is the validation javascript function

```
<script>
    function myFunction2() {
        if (Page_ClientValidate('S')) {
                                    document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('Button1').value = "Please waitً";
         }
 } 
</script>
```

The problem is the button is disabled after the text box has any value which did not pass the email  regex check

Code Behind

`protected void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }`

Comment: can we see ur code behind where you disable the button?

Comment: @Alander it is simple ADO.NET code to insert user email in MySQL database, i updated the question, i hope this helps you in testing. the problem is if the user input any letter it will accept it, the RegularExpressionValidator is USELESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about some client-side JavaScript magic:

```js
var goodEmail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
var goodEntry = /^^(?:(?:[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]*(?:\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]*)*)|(?:\"?.*\"?))@?(?:(?:\[?[0-9]{0,3}\.?[0-9]{0,3}\.?[0-9]{0,3}\.?[0-9]{0,3}\]?)|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\-0-9]*\.)*[a-zA-Z]{0,}))$/;

$("input")
  .data("oldValue", "")
  .bind("input propertychange", function() {
var $this = $(this);
var newValue = $this.val();

if (!goodEntry.test(newValue))
    return $this.val($this.data("oldValue"));
if (goodEmail .test(newValue)) {
    $this.removeClass("redborder");
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled",false);
}
else {
    $this.addClass("redborder");
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled",true);
}

return $this.data("oldValue", newValue);
  });

function submitit() {
    console.log($("#email").val() + " is valid: Ready to proceed!");
}
```

```css
.redborder { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Enter an email address:</p>
  <input id='email'>
  <button type='submit' disabled id='submitBtn' onclick="submitit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, client-side validation is simply not enough to be safe. All sorts of things can happen.

Answer (score 0):

It suppose to you wanna lock submit button during server side processing. For doesing the trick, use `OnClientClick` attribute of `asp:Button` in below approach:

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="Button1" 
  runat="server" 
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" 
  Text="Submit" 
  OnClick="Button1_Click" 
  UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
  OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Processing ...';" />
```

So the button will be disabled when user click on it, and it will be enabled when the server side operation will be finished.

Comment: No, i want to lock submit button Before Server Side Processing, thats why i am using the asp.net control RegularExpressionValidator